# Objective-C message passing system vs. Microsoft's WinAPI messaging

Tags: objective-c, c, winapi

I'm curious about something regarding Objective-C. Say, the following line of code:

```
[obj method:argument];
```

Is it similar to [Windows WinAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) sending a message provided via [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Or:

```
SendMessage(obj, method, argument, NULL);
```

I'm curious, because I'm quite proficient in C/C++ and Windows Win32, but I'm just learning Objective-C and I'm trying to understand its `message passing system`. And namely, if it is similar to what `SendMessage` does in Windows, and if so, such process of "calling" methods in Objective-C could be *relatively slow* for C/C++. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know about `SendMessage` in Windows. But ObjC method dispatching is slower than C++ method call.

Comment: FWIW, take a look at the objc_msgSend (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend) function and its specialized friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C messaging is slightly different. Messages are not put in a queue (PostMessage) which is then serviced by the OS, they are performed directly on the relevant class (more or less like SendMessage), so they are generally a little faster than Windows messages, if you regard that most Windows messages are posted, not sent directly.

Invoking a method in Objective-C means that the name of the method is searched, which results in a unique identifier, a selector. This search can usually be done at compile time. The class is queried if it implements that selector, and if it does, the correspondent code is called, with the appropriate parameters. If it does not exist, an exception is thrown (see comments by Bryan Chen). If the instance on which the method is invoked is nil, it is simply ignored.

As you see, this is more or less similar to how Windows SendMessage works, but not entirely.

As the comment says, it is (quite a bit) slower than member function calling in C++, even slower than calling virtual functions.

More can be found in the [Objective-C runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks. Windows does the whole lot more than that. For instance, it does `message marshalling` that ensures secure message sending and argument handling between threads and especially processes. All that takes a tremendous amount of time (well, in comparison to a direct C/C++ method call.)

Comment: OS X + Objective-C can do that too, AFAIK. But the usual object method call is more or less like a plain SendMessage.

Comment: "If it does not exist, the message is ignored." it is not ignored. the runtime will try fallback search path (`forwardInvocation:`) and if still not found, throw exception.

Comment: "Sending a message to an object that does not handle that message is an error. However, before announcing the error, the runtime system gives the receiving object a second chance to handle the message":
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objcruntimeguide/articles/ocrtforwarding.html

Comment: @Bryan: you are completely right. I somehow confused that with invoking a method on nil: that will not have any consequences, which is entirely different from how this works in a C++ method call (especially a virtual method call in C++)